# How to check if a YAML string excludes any useful information

Tags: ruby, yaml

### Context

When loading a blank YAML file `false` is returned. I do not want to discuss if this behavior makes sense or if it should be changed - that [discussion](https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/149) already takes place. Some examples:

```
YAML.load("")      #=> false
YAML.load("\n")    #=> false
YAML.load(" \n")   #=> false
```

And for context:

```
YAML.load("false") #=> false

YAML.load("---")   #=> nil
YAML.load("null"). #=> nil
YAML.load("nil")   #=> "nil"
```

I found this code in [`ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-1/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb#L45) that tries to work around this behavior and provide a useful (in this context) fallback:

```
def deserialize(config)
  config.present? ? YAML.load(config, content_path) : {}
end
```

And at the first glance it looks like it might work because `config.present?` (with `config` being a YAML string) would return `false` for all the examples above:

```
"".present?        #=> false
"\n".present?      #=> false
" \n".present?     #=> false
```

But here is the catch: This is the content of an example [`EncryptedConfiguration` file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-1/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/encrypted_file/encrypted_file_generator.rb#L18) generated by Rails itself:

```
def encrypted_file_template
  <<-YAML.strip_heredoc
  # aws:
  #   access_key_id: 123
  #   secret_access_key: 345
  YAML
end
```

Because

```
"# aws:\n#   access_key_id: 123\n#   secret_access_key: 345\n" => true
```

does *not* trigger the fallback to `{}` parsing that example will fail in [this method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-1/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb#L32)

```
def config
  @config ||= deserialize(read).deep_symbolize_keys
end
```

with a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'deep_symbolize_keys' for false:FalseClass` exception.

### Question

I want to return a fallback like `{}` instead of `false` when the string passed to `YAML.load` does not include any useful YAML syntax. But in situations in which `false` is a valid response (like `YAML.load("false")`) I do not want to return the fallback.

Is there a better way to return a fallback then this?

```
value = YAML.load(yaml)
return FALLBACK if value == false && yaml.strip != "false"
value
```

Comment: I would remove comments manually: `File.load(file_name).readlines.reject { |l| l[/^\s*#/] }.join($/)`.

Comment: In your solution, you should at least `yaml.strip` it before comparing to `"false"`.

Comment: Seems like `YAML.load(yaml, fallback: YAML.parse('{}'))` would work. Not sure if `fallback` is part of Psych's public API, though.

Comment: You should return `FALLBACK` when yaml.strip is/equals the empty string and value otherwise

Comment: @Anthon That doesn't work for yaml strings like `#acb` - like described in the question.